# Extract metadata from multiple videos

Tags: linux, bash, video, sed, metadata

I am faced with a challenge that requires multiple aspects of bash. I work in Linux (precisely Debian Stretch). Here is the situation (for all points/problem I write along the solution I considered for now, but I'm open to other ideas) :

- I have videos of various types (and various upper-lower case), such as .mp4, .mov, .MOV, .MP4, .avi,... located in a directory (and spread across an almost un-structured tree of directories). To find all I tried to use the `find` command
- For each video, I need to extract some metadata (i.e. the name of the file, duration of video, size of file and date of creation/last modification). The package `mediainfo` yields (among a lot of other things) the required fields. 
  The output of `mediainfo` is a long list of fields with format : `<Tag>\t : <value>`. I need to extract values for fields *Complete name*, *Duration*, *File size* and *Encoded date*.
- So with all this information, I must filter the required fields value and put them in a CSV file. I considered using `sed`.

My goal is to achieve all these tasks either in a script or a small amount of separate commands.

The idea code (this code is hideously wrong, but you can get an idea) :

`find . -type f -name "*.[mp4|MP4|mov|MOV|avi|AVI]" -exec mediainfo {} | sed '/Complete name|Duration|File size|Encoded date/p' > myfile.csv \;`

Would you have any idea how to perform this task ? I feel terribly lost in combining find, exec and sed and outputting to a csv...

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Did you know, that `mediainfo` [has](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/mediainfo.1.html) `--Output=XML` parameter? Maybe it would be easier to parse xml or even use it instead of CSV? For working with xml you can use [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html).

Comment: Didn't know that, it might indeed be easier to parse. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally managed to write a script doing that. Probably not the best way to do, but here it is :

```
resFile="myresult.csv"
dstDir="./destination/"
srcDir="./source/"

#first copy all files at same level in dstDir (with preserve and update)
#this is somehow necessary, relative name for MOV files and mediainfo 
#do not seem to work together.
find $srcDir -type f \( -name "*.mp4" -o -name "*.mov" -o -name "*.MOV" -o -name "*.avi" \) -exec cp -up {} $dstDir \;

#then for each file, output mediainfo of file and keep only interesting tags. add ### between each file.
find $dstDir -type f \( -name "*.mp4" -o -name "*.mov" -o -name "*.MOV" -o -name "*.avi"\
    -exec sh -c " mediainfo --Output=XML {} | sed '1,15!d;/Duration\|Complete\|File_size\|Encoded_date/!d' >> $resFile && echo '########' >> $resFile" \; 

#removes tags : <Duration>42s 15ms</Duration> -> 42s 15ms
sed -i 's/^<.*>\(.*\)<.*>/\1/I' $resFile

#Extract exact filename (and not relative)
sed -i 's/^\.\/.*\/\(.*\)\.[mp4|MOV|mov|avi|MP4]/\1/' $resFile

#Puts fields for a file on a unique line separated with commas
sed -i 'N;s/\n/,/;N;s/\n/,/;N;s/\n/,/;N;s/\n/,/' $resFile

#remove all trailing ###
sed -i 's/,#*$//' $resFile
```

I would still be interested if anyone has idea to improve the code.
I "minimized" a little bit, my actual code is a bit more modular and performs a few checks

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Due to less time,I was not able to complete. You just have to send output to CSV.

```
for c in $(locate --basename .mp4 .mkv .wmv .flv .webm .mov .avi)

do

 Complete_name=$(mediainfo --Output=XML $c | xml_grep 'Complete_name' --text_only| awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"}{print $NF}')

    echo $Complete_name

 Duration=$(mediainfo --Output=XML $c | xml_grep 'Duration' --text_only --nb_result 1)

    echo $Duration

 File_size=$(mediainfo --Output=XML $c | xml_grep 'File_size' --text_only)

echo $File_size

Encoded_date=$(mediainfo --Output=XML $c | xml_grep 'Encoded_date' --text_only -nb_result 1 | awk '{print $2}')

echo $Encoded_date

done
```

Comment: Looks nice. I would need some time to dive into it, and correct a few details, but it looks efficient. Thank you.